# Реализация алгоритма Ли

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, delphi-7

Есть ошибка в коде(acces violation),не понимаю почему она выскакивает.Портировал код с вики с си++ на делфи.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
const
  W=10;
  H=10;
  wall=50;
  blank=0;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Px:array [0..W*H{+1}] of Integer;          //убрал в коммы до того,как скинуть тебе,но не помогло
  Py:array [0..W*H{+1}] of Integer;
  len:Integer;
  grid:array [0..H{+1},0..W{+1}] of Integer;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}




function Proverka(ax,ay,bx,by:Integer):Boolean;
const
  dx:array[0..7] of Integer = (1,1,-1,-1,0,1,-1,0);
  dy:array[0..7] of Integer = (1,-1,-1,1,1,0,0,-1);
var
  d, x, y, k, iy, ix:integer;
  stop:Boolean;
begin

  if ((grid[ay,ax] = wall) or (grid[by,bx] = wall)) then Result:= false;

  d := 0;
  grid[ay,ax] := 0; //стартовая ячейка

  repeat
    stop := true;
    for  y := 0 to H do
      for  x := 0 to W do
        if  grid[y,x] = d then
           for  k := 0 to 8 do
           begin
             iy:=y + dy[k];
             ix:=x + dx[k];
             if  ((iy >= 0) and (iy < H) and (ix >= 0) and (ix < W) and (grid[iy,ix] = BLANK )) then
               stop := false;
               grid[iy,ix] := d + 1;

           end;
        Inc(d);
  until ((not stop) and  (grid[by,bx] = BLANK));

  if (grid[by,bx] = BLANK) then Result:= false;

  len:=grid[by,bx];
  x := bx;
  y := by;
  d := len;

   while ( d > 0 ) do
   begin
     px[d] := x;
     py[d] := y;                   // ?????????? ?????? (x, y) ? ????
     Dec(d);

     for k := 0 to 8 do
       iy:=y + dy[k];
       ix := x + dx[k];

       if ( (iy >= 0) and (iy < H) and (ix >= 0) and (ix < W) and (grid[iy,ix] = d)) then
         x := x + dx[k];
         y := y + dy[k];
         break;
    end;

  px[0] := ax;
  py[0] := ay;
  Result:=True;

end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j:Integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to StringGrid1.ColCount-1 do
  begin
    StringGrid1.Cells[0,i]:=IntToStr(i);
    StringGrid1.Cells[i,0]:=IntToStr(i);
  end;  

  for i:=1 to StringGrid1.ColCount-1 do
    for j:=1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do
      StringGrid1.Cells[i,j]:='0';

  with StringGrid1 do
  begin
    Cells[4,4]:='50';
    Cells[4,5]:='50';
    Cells[5,5]:='50';
    Cells[5,6]:='50';
    Cells[6,6]:='50';
    Cells[6,7]:='50';
    Cells[7,7]:='50';
    Cells[7,8]:='50';
  end;

 for i:=1 to 10 do
   for j:=1 to 10 do
     grid[i,j]:=StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[i,j]);

  Proverka(8,3,3,6);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Код вставьте в вопрос.

Comment: Вы, видимо, не уловили идею предыдущeго обсуждения. Это Ваша задача, сделать ответ на Ваш вопрос максимально легким. А Вы ставите перед потенциальными отвечающими препятствия в виде размещения кода на стороннем ресурсе.

Comment: @Igor нет,я просто тут недавно,не знаю,как тут код оформить

Comment: @HideME Хорошо, вставьте, как сможете - в этом Вам помогут.

Comment: @Igor неужели, получилось вставить код

Comment: @HideME отлично, и даже форматирование - приличное.

Comment: @Igor форматирую всегда

Comment: `0 to 8` равносильно диапазону `0<=x<=8`, это **9** значений, в массиве же `dx` и `dy` - всего 8.

Comment: Включите в настройках Project > Options > Compiler > Range checking, Overflow checking. Пересоберите проект и получите ошибку еще раз - IDE покажет вам строку в которой ошибка.

Comment: F7 F8 и F4 для отладки :)